# Derive the DE that is satisfied by the family of curves $2y=k(x^{2} + y^{2}) $

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

$2y=k(x^{2} + y^{2})$ can be rewritten as 
$y = cx^{2} + cy^{2}$

then differentiate both sides wrt x:

$dy/dx = 2cx + 2cy*dy/dx$

=> $ dy/dx ( 1 - 2cy)= 2cx $

=> dy/dx = 2cx/(1-2cy)

I checked my answer by substituting the given into my DE, and it is incorrect. WHat did I do wrong? How do you do questions like these in general? My textbook has no examples, and I can't find much online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hint: we have $y'(1-2cy)=2cx$ therefore we get $$y'=\frac{2cx}{1-2cy}$$
Shoulden't we not eliminate $c$ with the help of the given equation?
plugging $c=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}$ in the equation above we obtain $$y'=\frac{2xy}{x^2-y^2}$$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%27+%3D+2%28y%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%29x%2F%281-2%28y%2F%28x%5E2%2By%5E2%29%29y%29

the DE solution is not correct.

Comment: Are my prior steps correct?

Answer (score 2):

Since the constant $k$ comes from solving the differential equation, which means somehow it comes from the antiderivative process. So you will have to get rid of the $k$ when you take derivative by making it an additive constant. In this case, you can take natural log on both sides, so it becomes: $\ln{y}= \ln{\frac{k}{2}}+\ln{(x^2+y^2)}$. Now when you take derivative, the $k$ will disappear. Hope this helps.

Comment: Nice and simple. +1.